# How should a flight review be logged?

Tags: faa-regulations, logging

[14 CFR 61.56 (c)](http://rgl.faa.gov/Regulatory_and_Guidance_Library/rgFar.nsf/FARSBySectLookup/61.56) requires pilots to perform a [Flight Review](http://rgl.faa.gov/Regulatory_and_Guidance_Library/rgFar.nsf/FARSBySectLookup/61.56) every 24 calendar months unless another applicable action has been taken in order to be eligible to act as pilot in command of an airplane.

The [requirements of a flight review](http://rgl.faa.gov/Regulatory_and_Guidance_Library/rgFar.nsf/FARSBySectLookup/61.56) state that a minimum of 1 hour of flight instruction and 1 hour of ground instruction are required to complete that review.

My question concerns the logging of that activity. In the past my instructors have given me an signed logbook entry for the flight time, a description of the training received and materials reviewed a logbook endorsement stating that the flight review was performed. Most logbooks have a section for ground instruction, but I've never logged specific ground time there during a flight review. For a flight review to be valid does the ground instruction actually need to be logged separately from the flight instruction? Or is the ground instruction implied by the endorsement?

Answer (score 6):

Short answer: log it however you like as long as you log it.

[According to the FAA](http://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/AC%2061-98B.pdf):

> When the applicant has successfully  completed the review, the CFI
>   should endorse the pilot’s logbook to certify that the pilot has 
>   satisfactorily accomplished the flight review.  The CFI should make
>   the endorsement for a  satisfactory review in accordance with AC 61-
>   65. The flight and ground time must also be  logged in the pilot’s logbook in  accordance with § 61.51(a)(1)

[61.51(a)(1)](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/retrieveECFR?gp&r=PART&n=14y2.0.1.1.2#se14.2.61_151) simply says that "Training and aeronautical experience used to meet the requirements for a certificate, rating, or flight review of this part" must be logged.

So you do have to log both ground and flight time, but exactly *how* you do that is really up to you. The FAA doesn't require any specific logging format as long as the information is correct and CFIs, DPEs and others can see what they need to see.

Personally, I would note the ground time beside the CFI's endorsement and then log the flight time as I would for any other training flight. I've never met anyone who logged their 'ground instruction' time precisely (simulator time is a different story), but if you want to then you can do it any way that works for you. The FAA just wants you to log *something* that shows you did receive the necessary ground training.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the ground s hook column, and add it to the notes, like you do with student pilots.

Comment: rbp, please consider expanding your answer, it got flagged as low quality due to its length.